# Is it possible to check Latitude and Longitude is inside the viewport [drawn shape] or not [AT SERVER SIDE]

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

In Javascript (Client side), I could find out whether the given latitude and longitude is inside or outside the drawn shape by the contains method of `google.maps.LatLngBounds` class.

On the server side, is it possible to check whether the given coordinate is inside or outside the shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you do not need any function to check it out. Simple logic could do that.

Please try out the logic below.

**FOR RECTANGLE**

```
public void rectangleRegionChecker() {
    double Given_Lattitude;
    double Given_Longtitude;
    double SouthWestLattitude;
    double SouthWestLongtitude;
    double NorthEastLattitude;
    double NorthEastLongitude;
    if((SouthWestLattitude<=Given_lattitude)&&(SouthWestLongtitude<=Given_Longtitude)&&(NorthEastLattitude>=Given_Lattitude)&&(NorthEastLongtitude>=Given_Longtitude)){
    S.O.P("Inside the Rectangle");
    }
}
```

I believe this will help you a lot.

Comment: I understand the logic. But, Will it work for google maps api ?. Then what about Circle in Google Maps API